# Loop over excel files' paths under a directory and pass them to data manipulation function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, windows, operating-system, listdir

I need to check the excel files under a directory `/Users/x/Documents/test/` by `DataCheck` function from `data_check.py`, so I can do **data manipulation** of many excel files, `data_check.py` has code structure as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

def DataCheck(filePath):
    df = pd.read_excel(filePath)
    try:
        df = df.dropna(subset=['building', 'floor', 'room'], how = 'all')
        ...
        ...
        ...
        df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index = False)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    status = True
    while status:
        rawPath = input(r"")
        filePath = rawPath.strip('\"')
        if filePath.strip() == "":
            status = False
        DataCheck(filePath)
```

In order to loop all the excel files' paths under a directory, I use:

```
import os

directory = '/Users/x/Documents/test/'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx") or filename.endswith(".xls"):
        print(os.path.join(directory, filename))
    else:
        pass
```

Out:

```
/Users/x/Documents/test/test 3.xlsx
/Users/x/Documents/test/test 2.xlsx
/Users/x/Documents/test/test 4.xlsx
/Users/x/Documents/test/test.xlsx
```

But I don't know how to combine the code above together, to pass the excel files' paths to `DataCheck(filePath)`.

Thanks for your kind help at advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the function with the names instead of printing them:

```
import os

directory = '/Users/x/Documents/test/'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx") or filename.endswith(".xls"):
        fullname = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        DataCheck(fullname)
```